# Conditional rendering based on user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, conditional-rendering

I've just started learning React and am struggling with conditional rendering. I want to render components based on form input but i'm not sure what needs to be done or where it needs to be executed.

I have imported my Form component which has the input I want to use and have another component like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import CardOne from './CardOne';
import CardTwo from './CardTwo';
import CardThree from './CardThree';

export default class CardContainer extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <CardOne />
        <CardTwo />
        <CardThree />
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I basically want to be able to show certain Cards if the value of the input is greater than X when the form is submitted, but I don't know how to target an imported component.

This is my Form component:

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    number: ''
  };

  change = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState({
      number: ''
    })
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <form>
        <label>Number</label>
        <input
        type="number"
        name="number"
        placeholder="Number"
        value={this.state.number}
        onChange={e => this.change(e)} />

        <button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help will be massively appreciated!

Comment: i can help on this . . But i need some more clarification

Comment: What i understood was , For example :   If user Type 1 mean's u need to show one card component  , if user types 2 mean's CardTwo component  ..  Correct me if i'm wrong. . depends upon the user input you will show Card component right ?  ?

Comment: You have to incorporate your form somewhere, `CardsContainer` maybe. And besides that, the logic of filtering cards is not clear, as you can see from these comments. Can you add some more explanation?

Comment: Sorry if it was vague! What I mean is, if someone types in, for example, "10", cardOne shows. If they type in "20", cardsOne and cardTwo show. I hope that makes it a bit more clear!

Comment: Kind of multiple of 10? what if i type in 100?

Comment: 100 means 10 tabs i think .. .

Comment: what i told above is Your functionality . .right  ?

Comment: I was just using those numbers as examples. But yeh, if they types in anything greater than 20 all 3 cards would show. So CardOne shows for less than or equal to 10, CardTwo less than or equal to 20 and CardThree is greater than 20.

Comment: ONE MORE QUESTION   :  Card needs to be shown after user clicks the submit button or what ?

Comment: Yeh so the card components get shown when the submit button on the form is clicked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redesigned your Form component , Below is my code. . Let me know if u faced any issues on that .

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CardOne from './CardOne';
import CardTwo from './CardTwo';
import CardThree from './CardThree';

export default class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    number: '',
    showOne:true,
    showTwo:false,
    showThree:false,
    userInputValue:''
  };

  change = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      userInputValue: e.target.value
    });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
    if (this.state.userInputValue > 10 && this.state.userInputValue <20 ){
      this.setState({
        showTwo: true,
      })
    }
    if (this.state.userInputValue > 20 && this.state.userInputValue < 30) {
      this.setState({
        showThree: true,
      })
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form>
        <label>Number</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="number"
          placeholder="Number"
          value={this.state.userInputValue}
          onChange={e => this.change(e)} />

        <button onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>
      {this.state.showOne ? 
            <CardOne />
       :
       <div></div>
      }
      {this.state.showTwo ?
        <CardTwo />
        :
        <div></div>
      }
      {this.state.showThree ?
        <CardThree />
        :
        <div></div>
      }
      </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// What i wrote above is your base functionality . You reedit the condition depends on ur requirement .
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it! I just tried it and it's not letting me enter a number into the input...

Comment: pls change this line  -->  value={this.state.number} to --- value={this.state.userInputValue}

Comment: Really appreicate it! That's the base functionality I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with following your logic of card rendering. I did not change Form coponent but rather worked on the Container

```js
export default class CardContainer extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
       number: 0,
    }
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }
   onFormSubmit=(number)=>{
     this.setState({ number: number });
   }
  
  render(){
    let i=Math.floor(this.state.number/10) 
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={() => this.onFormSubmit(number)}
        [<CardOne />, <CardTwo />, <CardThree/>].slice(0,i).map(card => 
            {card} 
        )
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use render prop for this kind of problem. You can research more about render props but basically your CardContainer component will not render those cards component statically as it is. It will return props.children instead.

And then you will have a function (i.e function TestX) that will have a conditional to check what the value of X is. This is the function that will return either  , ,  based on what X is. The function TestX will receive props from CardContainer, including the value of X that is read from the state.

So I will just use CardContainer component with  as its child.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm still in very early days with learning React so will definitely look into how to render props!